# for loop inside pg function

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, plpgsql

I have the following pg script

```
create or replace function ended_jobs()
returns table(
 "Time Range" timestamptz,
 "Ended Jobs" numeric
) as $$
begin
return query SELECT date_trunc('HOUR',date_interval) as "Time Range", sum(COALESCE(end_count,0)) "Ended Jobs"  
FROM "job_start_end_rollups"  
right join ( (select   current_timestamp - interval '0 HOUR' date_interval)  
union all (select   current_timestamp - interval '1 HOUR' date_interval) 
union all (select   current_timestamp - interval '2 HOUR' date_interval) 
union all (select   current_timestamp - interval '3 HOUR' date_interval) 
union all (select   current_timestamp - interval '4 HOUR' date_interval) 
union all (select   current_timestamp - interval '5 HOUR' date_interval) 
union all (select   current_timestamp - interval '6 HOUR' date_interval) 
union all (select   current_timestamp - interval '7 HOUR' date_interval) 
union all (select   current_timestamp - interval '8 HOUR' date_interval) 
union all (select   current_timestamp - interval '9 HOUR' date_interval) 
union all (select   current_timestamp - interval '10 HOUR' date_interval) 
union all (select   current_timestamp - interval '11 HOUR' date_interval) 
union all (select   current_timestamp - interval '12 HOUR' date_interval) 
union all (select   current_timestamp - interval '13 HOUR' date_interval) 
union all (select   current_timestamp - interval '14 HOUR' date_interval) 
union all (select   current_timestamp - interval '15 HOUR' date_interval) )  
date_intervals on date_trunc('HOUR', TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + chunk_start_time * interval '1 millisecond' ) = date_trunc('HOUR',date_interval)   
GROUP BY date_part('HOUR',TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + chunk_start_time * interval '1 millisecond'),date_interval  
ORDER BY date_interval LIMIT 16;
end;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

After running the above mentioned pg script I could get the data

```
select * from ended_jobs()
```

How can I write 'for loop' inside the right join to avoid multiple 'union all', like this

```
.......
right join ( (select   current_timestamp - interval '0 HOUR' date_interval)
for i in 1..16 loop
union all (select   current_timestamp - concat(i,' HOUR')::INTERVAL date_interval) 
end loop;
........
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't need `plpgsql` for this. A simple [SQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html) will be enough. Also: the language name is an identifier, do not put that into single quotes: it should be `language plpgsql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` for that:

```
FROM "job_start_end_rollups"  
  right join generate_series(current_timestamp - interval '15 HOUR',
                             current_timestamp, 
                             interval '1 hour') as date_intervals(date_interval) 
             ON ....
```

You can also move the `date_trunc()` into that:

```
right join (
  select date_trunc('HOUR',di) as date_interval
  from generate_series(current_timestamp - interval '15 HOUR',
                       current_timestamp, 
                       interval '1 hour') as t(di)
) as date_intervals ON .... = date_intervals.date_interval
```

Comment: @KhachaturSaribekyan: if that solved you problem, please accept the answer so that your question is marked as resolved.